# Declare a Table Variable based on dynamic pivot columns statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to declare a table variable and fill it from the pivot with dynamic column to perform join statement.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = 
   STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColName)
   FROM [sbs].[ProposalAmounts]
   GROUP BY ColName, ProposalID
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SET @query = N'SELECT ProposalID, ' + @cols + N' from
   (select ProposalID, Amount, ColName from [sbs].[ProposalAmounts]) x
   PIVOT
   (MAX(Amount)for ColName in (' + @cols + N')) p '
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

This is what I've done so far and I'm confused as to how to declare a table variable that has dynamic columns in it.

This is the result of the query above:

[image: 1]

And this is the result of the table I want to perform join statement:

[image: 2]

Comment: Can you provide sample data and how desired results would look like?

Comment: You can't declare such a variable, period. If you do that you'd have to generate the declaration, meaning the whole statement must be dynamic. T-SQL hates dynamic anything.

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . Not only T-SQL hates dynamic anything. I personally hate it as well. ;) As I see it, a DBMS was never meant for such kinds of dynamic data processing.

Comment: @SirchDcmp I have updated the question with pictures

Comment: @JeroenMostert I also hate it but I cant think of any way to do it haha

Comment: @Mike . . . Your question seems to indicate an XY-problem, meaning that you might have an underlying issue that should actually be solved in an alternative way. Can you perhaps think of a way of processing your data without using a pivoted query here for now, for example? If you need help with that, we also need to know what you want to do with the data in that table variable. So you probably need to specify a lot more details in your question for that.

Comment: Without sample data (and consumable samples, not images), this is unclear what you're asking. Showing us what your failed attempt generates can often not be too helpful when we don't know what your original data looks like. Take the time to produce a [mre], so that we can help you get to the goal you want.

Comment: `SELECT...INTO @table...` would do the trick, so long as the rest of the code was dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jeroen Mostert commented, you need to make everything dynamic.

I would suggest to put the join inside the dynamic query. Instead of a table variable, I use a common table expression.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = 
   STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + QUOTENAME([ColName])
          FROM [_tmp_].[ProposalAmounts]
          GROUP BY [ColName], [ProposalID]
          FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'')

SET @query = N'
WITH [CTE_Pivoted_ProposalAmounts] AS
(
  SELECT [ProposalID], ' + @cols + N'
  FROM
    (SELECT [ProposalID], [Amount], [ColName] FROM [sbs].[ProposalAmounts]) x
    PIVOT (MAX([Amount]) FOR [ColName] IN (' + @cols + N')) p
)
SELECT *
FROM
  [sbs].[OtherTable] ot
  INNER JOIN [CTE_Pivoted_ProposalAmounts] ppa ON ppa.[ProposalID] = ot.[ProposalID];
';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

You need to replace `[sbs].[OtherTable]` with the actual name of the table you want to join with. And you might also tweak the join criteria and the fields in the SELECT clause. This code here is just a simple example. I assume you will manage to fix the query yourself to make it behave as you expect.